# Dojo File Caching in Worklight

Tags: caching, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

When using Dojo file caching with Worklight receiving a 404 Error when running in Simulator.  It appears the file being loaded is not being copied from the common area to the device.  Is there something else I need to define in my project to make that happen?  There must be a convention and I wanted to follow it going forward as I expect to have more template files in the project.

My define statement in a .js file:

```
define(["dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/dom", "dojo/text!./templates/Order.html"], function(lang, ContentPane, dom, template){
...
var cp1 = new ContentPane({
            title:"Order",
            content: lang.replace(template, someJson)
         }).placeAt("temp");
```

My folder structure:
In the common/js directory I have the above code in a .js file and I have a templates folder to keep the Order.html and I would expect to have other template files stored there in the future.

Error on the console:

```
GET http://localhost:10080/DojoProject/apps/services/preview/DojoApp/windowsphone8/1.0/default/layers/templates/Order.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the way you are specifying the path, browser tries to find the file in the "layers" folder which is sibling to "templates".

Have you tried to modify the "dojo/text!./templates/Order.html" to something like: "dojo/text!./../templates/Order.html" to navigate one level up, then go into the templates folder?

I'm not sure this will work, but I think it worths a try.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reply, I had given that a try before.  From the best I can tell it looks like Worklight is not copying over the template file after generating.  The only work around I could find to get this working was to manually stage the file to the Windows Phone target but this is not a great solution since common files like this should be accessible by all devices.